# telnet send a http request

Tags: http, post

I am using telnet to send a http request , like this:

```
telnet> open 192.168.4.135 8087
Trying 192.168.4.135...
Connected to 192.168.4.135.
Escape character is '^]'.
POST /rpc/ HTTP/1.1
HOST:192.168.4.135:8087
Content-length:18
Content-type:application/x-http-form-urlencoded

action=loadrsctype
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 17 May 2012 03:52:53 GMT
Content-Length: 45
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

return=fail&error=Configuration doesn't existHTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
Date: Thu, 17 May 2012 03:52:53 GMT
Content-Length: 94

<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>400 Bad Request</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Bad Request</H1>
</BODY></HTML>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

the response code is 200 , but why there is a paragraph like this :

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
Date: Thu, 17 May 2012 03:52:53 GMT
Content-Length: 94

<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>400 Bad Request</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Bad Request</H1>
</BODY></HTML>
```

This is the output of the server or telnet itself ? How to avoid to show this ?

--update--
When i change "HTTP/1.1" to "http/1.1", i get the right response. 
Now i wonder wheather this is requirement of protocol or related with the implementation of the server?

Comment: It looks like the content of the "200 OK" response is "return=fail&error=Configuration doesn't exist", so it doesn't look like this has worked at all. Are you sure that URL is OK?

Comment: I think the url has no problem. It seems there are TWO responses. The first one (return=fail&error=Configuration doesn't exist) is what i expected, but the second one is not.

Answer (score 5):

In `HTTP 1.1`, all connections are considered `persistent` unless declared otherwise.

Then... I think the server is receiving some spurious newline char and reply with a `Bad Request`.

If you use `http/1.1` instead of `HTTP/1.1` could make fallback the version to the version `1.0` that's not persistent by default and after the `200 OK` response it drops the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `&` with `&amp;`.

Answer (score 0):

The code at the URL you are accessing is printing some text:

```
return=fail&error=Configuration doesn't exist
```

But then your code continues on to print a HTTP 400 error.  Probably you forgot to abort after printing the response, and so your code goes on to print the HTTP 400 as well.

Comment: so, I really think that the problem is the server.

Comment: @ccsnailpp: Yes, the problem is the code on the server has a bug in it.  (Sorry, I was assuming it was your code running on the server!)

Comment: yes, it should be. the server is neither apache nor nginx. it is a tiny server implemented by our team.